# Post error with ionic and cloud functions

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, cors

I'm trying to call a function and it returns this CORS error:

IONIC:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})


return this.HttpClient.post("***********************************", datos, httpOptions);
```

CLoud (Node.js):

```
import * as cors from 'cors';
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});
exports.EnviarCodigo = functions.region('us-central1').https.onCall(async (req:any, res:any) => {
  corsHandler(req, res, async () => { 
    return res.send(true)  
  });
});
```

Error:
Request from another origin blocked: Same-origin policy prevents reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-banandu-f08f8.cloudfunctions.net/EnviarCodigo (reason: missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ). Status code: 403

I don't understand why it gives me this error.
If anyone can help me it will make my day